# transparent socks redirector Apache License

Tags: android

I'm currently creating an Android application thaw will set http, https, socks and ftp transparent proxy configuration. I found existing application and I tried to use their socks redirector but lately I found out that it is under GNU license.

Are they any socks redirector under Apache License? I researched and I found some but under GNU/GPL.

Comment: GNU/GPL doesn't disallow you to use the application commercially, it "only" force you to provide the source code along with your compiled version and to use the GNU/GPL license for your derived work. Also it's only the "Apache" license, not "Apache GPL" but this may be confusing.

Comment: @Manhim - I understand I'm sorry I will edit my post. Thanks a lot. I still hope there are existing socks redirector under Apache license.

Comment: @Manhim - I would like to confirm something. First I created a bash file and that bash file are using an GPL'ed library, now my Android application are executing the bash file. Does it mean my Android application is now under GPLv3??

Comment: No. You can use a library or a software as long as you don't modify it directly you don't have to provide the source code or GPL-ify your code. As long as you don't use any of the code from the GPLd software you should be ok. Please note that I can't replace a lawyer on this subject :)

Comment: @Manhim - I fully understand now, I'm really sorry because I'm really confused in GNU/GPL license that's why I wanted to ask here in stackoverflow. Because of this issue I tried to build my GPL'ed libraries from static to Dynamic Link Library just to have a GNU Lesser General Public License T_T but since I got your answer I think I don't have to do it anymore. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Do you plan on modifying the GPL'd application or simply use it?  If you are utilizing the application and not linking it to your code, I think you can still release your application as a commercial product and use the GPL's application.

Comment: I'm using existing socks transparent redirector (redsocks) it is under GPLv3. I'm currently using it as redirector in my android application, the problem is my project will be commercially release.

Comment: @standalone - I will be interested in seeing what Manhim says, but if I understand what you are doing above, I do not think your application is under the GPLv3 if you just executing a script that is calling the GPL'd application.  If you are simply using a GPL'd application it does not mean your application becomes GPL'd also, only if you alter or create a "derivative" of the GPL'd application.  Which I do not think your are doing.

Comment: yep I'm also interested. But basically my application will wont work without that GPL library, my andrpod application is totally dependent to that library.